# Standard rollup fields performance consideration

Tags: roll-up-summary

From my research it seems that rollups do not consume CPU limit because they are part of DML. I am aware that rollups trigger parent object update.

Am I correct to assume that there is no impact on CPU limit, if I implement appropriate trigger/flow bypasses on parent object? Or there is something else that is still impacted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. CPU time is not used while database events are happening, including validations and rollup summary calculations. In most cases, it's probably harmless to allow the parent triggers to run as well, unless you have some pretty heavy logic.

Comment: Thanks! Had a dilemma between standard and custom rollups. And since standard rollups fulfill my requirement, better to go for a solution that doesn't consume more CPU time.